# weak convergence implies bounded in $L^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Prove:

> Let E be a measurable set and $1\le p <\infty$ suppose $f_n$ weakly convergence to $f$ in $L^p(E)$. then $f_n$ is bounded in $L^p(E)$

This the theorem in Royden fourth edition page 164.
The book proves it by contradiction,assume it's unbounded then use problem 18. Then I got lost...

I don't understand why we can take scalar and take subsequence to get equation (18).

I have tried to prove problem18.

First since unbounded,there must be a subsequence with $\|f_{n_k}\|\ge n3^n$.then since sequence $\|f_{n_k}\|/n3^n$ exisit convergence subsequence(in extended real value).then we have $\|f_{n_k}\|/n3^n$ then it constructs a $g_n$.I got lost then. What's the motivation of the problem.And how to use it in thereom above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a way to prove problem 18.

I believe the problem is trying to show: if $f_n$ converges to $f$ weakly and is unbounded, then there is a weakly convergent sequence $g_n$ with $||g_n||=n 3^n$.

(P.S. Note that it is a well-known fact that every weakly convergent sequence is always bounded)

So, Given a weakly convergent unbounded $f_n$, we can find a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ such that $||f_{n_k}||\ge k 3^k=\alpha_k$.

Observe that $1\ge \alpha_k/||f_{n_k}||\ge0$. The sequence of real numbers $\{\alpha_k/||f_{n_k}||\}_{k=1}^\infty$ has a convergent subsequence (of the form $\{a_{k_j}/||f_{n_{k_j}}||\}_{j=1}^\infty$) So the desired sequence $g_n$ can be defined by $$g_j=\frac{a_{k_j}}{||f_{n_{k_j}}||}f_{n_{k_j}},\hspace{0.5cm}j=1,2,\dots$$It can be checked that $g_n$ defined in this way is weakly convergent and $||g_n||=n 3^n$.

Comment: I have a question about the above,that is why we need to check $\{a_{k_j}/||f_{n_{k_j}}||\}_{j=1}^\infty$ convergence,is it becasue  after that $g_j$ weakly convergent by linearity of $T$?

Comment: yes it is needed to establish the weak convergence of $g_j$

Comment: By the way can you explain the construction of $\epsilon_n$ a bit after that in the theorem,that is $\epsilon_{n+1}=1 / 3^{n+1} \text { if } \int_{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n} \epsilon_{k}\left(f_{n}\right)^{*}\right] \cdot f_{n+1} \geq 0$,is there some typo?

Comment: The definition of $\epsilon_n$ is to deduce the first part of equation (19)

Comment: I am not sure what typo you are talking

Comment: Should be $\epsilon_{n+1}=1 / 3^{n+1} \text { if } \int_{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n} \epsilon_{k}\left(f_{k}\right)^{*}\right] \cdot f_{n+1} \geq 0$ instead of  $\epsilon_{n+1}=1 / 3^{n+1} \text { if } \int_{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n} \epsilon_{k}\left(f_{n}\right)^{*}\right] \cdot f_{n+1} \geq 0$ ?

Comment: yeah I think you're right

Comment: Then I don't know how to get the first part of inequality in (19),can you provides some hints?

Comment: I would say the inequality is by direct calculation, it is quite standard

Comment: Yeah I get it,thanks for your help.